# Display large vector collections in WebGL

Tags: three.js, webgl, cad, deck.gl, vector-tiles

I was looking at [three.js](https://threejs.org) as a replacement of [deck.gl](https://deck.gl) in our existing [WebGL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API) software, for reasons not relevant to this question. One of the input data sources is large vector data exported from CAD systems. One scene integrates about 5 collections of linear features and areas in the scene. Each such collection is 10-50MB SVG. In deck.gl, we did a crazy but very effective hack - converted the vectors to geo coordinates and used lazy loading via deck.gl [tile layer](https://deck.gl/docs/api-reference/geo-layers/tile-layer). It improved the rendering performance tremendously but required additional tweaking, because majority of the data is still in cartesian coordinates.

**I haven't found a comparable lazy loading of such large vector data in three.js**. There are plenty of format-specific loaders but it's still just different means of upfront loading. While [vector tiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_tiles) were created in geographical context, the principle of pre-rendering and pre-tiling data for lazy loading should be universally applicable? But i could not find any non-geo implementation, the less with support in three.js. Our geo-hacking was effective, but never felt correct because the model is naturally cartesian. The internets are suggesting that [Cesium](https://cesium.com/platform/cesiumjs/) may be more flexible than deck.gl for our new requirements, but we would prefer to avoid the geo-hacking, not dive deeper in it.

What did i miss?